# Why does HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType throw null reference exception?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Here is my code:

```
 string bound = "----------------------------" +DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
 HttpRequestMessage httpreq = new HttpRequestMessage();
 httpreq.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound);
```

which throws the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.Content.get returned null.

I don't know why is this happening.

Can anyone help me to correct my code?

Comment: try this `if (httpreq.Content == null)
{
    httpreq.Content = new StringContent("");
   
}`

Comment: how to use this? can u provide full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.[ContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage?view=winrt-19041) throws null reference exception in c#?

`System.Net.Http` api is used to cross-platform. And it could not support UWP completely. In UWP platform we suggest you use [`Windows.Web.Http`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http?view=winrt-19041) namespace to replace.

```
using Windows.Web.Http;


string bound = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
HttpRequestMessage httpreq = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpreq.Content.Headers.ContentType = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound);
```